# Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bigbluebutton/ubuntu/support' Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ppa

When I run this command I get error...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bigbluebutton/support -y
```

OR

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rmescandon/yq -y
```

I get the following error.

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bigbluebutton/ubuntu/support'.

ERROR: '~bigbluebutton' user or team does not exist.
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I dont know can you please tell me how to check proxy setting

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`  and `sudo apt update` also `ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep python` Add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
We just tried on a test server and it worked

# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bigbluebutton/support -y
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpp8oro48q/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpp8oro48q/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E95B94BC from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpp8oro48q/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E95B94BC: public key "Launchpad PPA for BigBlueButton" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Comment: I get same error.                                                                                                           
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bigbluebutton/ubuntu/support'.

ERROR: '~bigbluebutton' user or team does not exist.

Comment: bbb-install latest

New GCP VM ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-minimal-2004-lts

`# add-apt-repository ppa:bigbluebutton/support -y
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bigbluebutton/ubuntu/support'.
The team named '~bigbluebutton' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/support'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'support':  BigBlueButton Support Packages`